# How to access JDBC datasource using JDNI on weblogic server without using wlfullclient.jar?

Tags: java, jdbc, weblogic, jndi

I have a Java standalone application which accesses a JDBC data source using JNDI lookup on a WebLogic server using wlfullclient.jar.
Now that wlfullclient.jar is deprecated, so I have to modify the Java application without using wlfullclient.jar.
How to write the application without using wlfullclient.jar?

Comment: Try using the wlthint3client.jar instead. It is located under the wlserver/server/lib folder.

Comment: But for wlthin3client.jar, there is a limitation on "JDBC resources, including WebLogic JDBC extensions.". So I think it cannot be used. Ref : https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/12213/wls/SACLT/wlthint3client.htm#SACLT387

Comment: hum, you're right, the remote datasource lookup over RMI is not supported with thin client library. Unfortunately, JDBC over RMI is also deprecated for security reasons. Oracle recommends to use the jdbc driver to create connections to the database.

Comment: Do you mean that we can use just JDBC drivers to create he Datasource ? How is it different when using wlfullclient.jar ?

Comment: no, you cannot create a datasource using JDBC but you can create a connection to your database

Comment: Datasource is pre created. I don't want to create datasource, but want to connect to database and insert row in a table. What jars and packages to use.

Comment: You can directly create a SQL connection to your database from the jdbc driver without any datasource.